# Passing in an operator in Java

Tags: java

I want to reduce code by passing in an operator but I am not sure how to do this. For example, in the two functions below, both have the same code except for a less than vs greater than sign

```
private int findMin(int[] a){
    int min =a[0];
    for (int val : a){
        if (val<min){
             min=val;
        }
    }
}

private int findMax(int[] a){
    int max =a[0];
    for (int val : a){
        if (val>max){
             min=val;
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking one solution to reduce code would be to make an interface called executable with the declared method execute(int a, int b) which returns a boolean. 
Then I could create two implementations, one which executes < and one which executes >. Something like:

```
private int find(int[] a, Executable myOp){
    int cur =a[0];
    for (int val : a){
        if (myOp.execute(val,cur)){
             cur=val;
        }
    }
} 
private int findMax(int[] a){
    GreaterThan g = new GreaterThan();
    find(a, g)
}
   private int findMin(int[] a){
    LessThan g = new LessThan();
    find(a, g)
}
```

*where GreaterThan and LessThan implement Executable

I recognize this is totally unnecessary for my example, but I can see more complex examples where it would be beneficial to create extra functionality by changing a single "operation". Is what I described the standard way to approach my dilemma or is there something else I should consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is what I described the standard way to approach my dilemma or is there something else I should consider?

Your proposed way of implementing this would be best described as an "old fashioned" way of doing it.  What you are proposing is essentially the [Strategy design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) implemented (by hand) at a fine-grained level.

In Java 8 (and onwards) the standard way to do this would be to use the `Stream` APIs and implement your "operators" as lambda expressions or similar.  The infrastructure already exists, so there is no point re-inventing it.

Even if what you want to implement doesn't map nicely to the functional style of programming provided by streams, you can still use Java 8 lambda expressions and functional interfaces to code your "operators" and pass them to your (hypothetical) non-stream-like algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Java already provides a mechanism by which you can do this, using [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). I have made the methods `static` because they do not depend on any class data, and I have added a small test harness. It might look something like,

```
private static int find(int[] a, Comparator<Integer> myOp) {
    int cur = a[0];
    for (int val : a) {
        if (myOp.compare(val, cur) > 0) {
            cur = val;
        }
    }
    return cur;
}

private static int findMax(int[] a) {
    return find(a, Comparator.naturalOrder());
}

private static int findMin(int[] a) {
    return find(a, Comparator.reverseOrder());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] vals = { 1, 2, 3 };

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));
    System.out.println("min: " + findMin(vals));
    System.out.println("max: " + findMax(vals));
}
```

And I get

```
[1, 2, 3]
min: 1
max: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int min = Arrays.stream(a).min().getAsInt();
int max = Arrays.stream(a).max().getAsInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

The more general version of what you want is already done:

```
int maxInArray = IntStream.of(array).reduce(Integer.MIN_VALUE, (acc,x) -> (acc>=x ? acc:x));

int sumOfArray = IntStream.of(array).reduce(0, (acc,x) -> acc+x));

int oddNumberCount = IntStream.of(array).reduce(0, (acc,x) -> (x&1)==1 ? acc+1 : acc));
```

etc...

Go ahead and write a function that finds the minimum if you're gonna call it a lot, but I wouldn't bother making clever generalized versions, since the Stream API already covers those use cases.